# How to calculate % of a label in column and use this in ggplot2 facet graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

this might be a simple question but it's been a while that I used R.

I try to create a facet graph with ggplot2.
The data I use is like

```
structure(list(Resolved = c("Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", "Jan-23", 
"Jan-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Feb-23", 
"Feb-23", "Feb-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", 
"Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Mar-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", "Apr-23", 
"Apr-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", "May-23", 
"May-23", "May-23"), Tag1 = c("A15", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A15", 
"A09", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", 
"A23", "A15", "A09", "A15", "A23", "A09", "A15", "A23", "A23", 
"A23", "A15", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A15", "A09", "A13", "A23", 
"A15", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A15", 
"A23", "A13", "A15", "A13", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A15", 
"A15", "-", "A23", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A09", "A15", 
"A15", "A15", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A11", "A15", 
"A23", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A15", "A09", "A09", "A13", "A15", 
"A09", "A09", "A23", "A11", "A11", "A15", "A09", "A15", "A15", 
"A09", "A15", "A13", "A15", "A15", "A13", "A13", "A23", "A23", 
"-", "A15", "A23", "A09", "A15", "A23", "A09", "A13", "A15", 
"A09", "A15", "A15", "A13", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A11", "A23", 
"A09", "A15", "-", "-", "A09", "A13", "A15", "A23", "A15", "A09", 
"A13", "A15", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", 
"A15", "A15", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A13", "A23", "A09", "A23", 
"A15", "A09", "A13", "A09", "A13", "A13", "A15", "A23", "A23", 
"A15", "A15", "A15", "A09", "A13", "A15", "A15", "A09", "A13", 
"A15", "A15", "A13", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A09", 
"A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A11", 
"A09", "A09", "A23", "A20", "A23", "A15", "A09", "A09", "A13", 
"A23", "A09", "A09", "-", "A09", "A09", "A09", "A13", "A23", 
"A09", "A13", "A15", "A09", "A13", "A15", "A09", "A23", "A23", 
"A23", "A23", "A15", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A20", "A09", "-", 
"A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A13", "A15", "A09", "A23", 
"A15", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A15", "-", 
"A09", "A09", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A13", "A20", "A23", 
"A09", "A09", "A23", "A13", "A23", "A23", "A11", "A15", "A23", 
"A09", "A23", "A15", "A09", "A17", "A23", "A20", "A13", "A15", 
"A09", "A13", "A13", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A13", "A15", "A09", 
"A09", "A23", "A13", "-", "A09", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A23", 
"A09", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A23", "-", "A23", "A09", "A23", 
"A15", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A11", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A13", 
"A15", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A09", 
"A09", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A13", 
"A23", "A11", "A15", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A09", "A09", 
"A23", "A15", "A13", "A23", "A09", "A15", "A23", "A23", "A23", 
"A23", "A23", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A23", 
"A09", "A15", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A13", "A23", "A23", "A15", 
"A23", "A23", "A15", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A23", "A09", 
"A15", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A15", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", 
"A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A15", "A09", "A15", "A23", 
"A09", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A13", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A09", 
"A09", "A23", "A09", "-", "A15", "A09", "A23", "A13", "A13", 
"A23", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A09", 
"A09", "A09", "A23", "A15", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A15", "A09", 
"A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A13", "A09", "A11", "A13", 
"A15", "A23", "A09", "A23", "-", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A09", 
"-", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A15", "-", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A09", 
"A15", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A13", "A23", "A09", "A15", "A15", 
"A13", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A13", "A13", 
"A09", "A13", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A09", "A13", "A09", 
"A23", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A13", "A09", "A15", "A09", "A11", 
"A09", "A13", "A23", "A15", "A09", "A09", "A15", "A15", "A15", 
"A23", "A15", "A15", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A15", "A15", "A23", 
"A23", "A23", "A15", "A13", "A23", "A13", "A11", "A09", "A15", 
"A15", "A09", "A15", "A09", "A13", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A13", 
"A15", "A11", "A23", "-", "A11", "A15", "A09", "A15", "A09", 
"A09", "-", "A23", "A23", "A13", "A09", "A15", "-", "A15", "A23", 
"A23", "A23", "A09", "-", "A23", "A23", "A15", "A09", "A09", 
"A09", "A23", "A13", "A09", "A09", "A09", "A11", "A23", "A09", 
"A23", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A09", "A23", "A22", "A09", 
"A09", "A13", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A15", "A23", "A23", "A15", 
"A23", "A15", "A13", "A13", "-", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A09", 
"A09", "A23", "A09", "A15", "A15", "A23", "A15", "A23", "A15", 
"A09", "A23", "A15", "-", "A23", "A15", "A09", "A13", "A23", 
"A15", "A23", "A15", "A23", "A23", "-", "A13", "A15", "A23", 
"A15", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A15", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A23", 
"A09", "A23", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A23", "A09", "A23", "A15", 
"A15", "A15", "A15", "A13", "A23", "A23", "A13", "A09", "A09", 
"A09", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A09", "A23", "A23", "A23", 
"A23", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A23", "A09", "A09", "A15", "A13", 
"A11", "A23", "A15", "-", "A23", "A09", "A15", "A09", "A09", 
"A15", "A15", "A23", "A15", "A15", "A09", "A09", "A09", "A15", 
"A15", "A09", "A09", "-", "A09", "A09"), Tag2 = c("C23", "C10", 
"C04", "C23", "C23", "C10", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C10", "C10", 
"C23", "C13", "C21", "C10", "C13", "C23", "C13", "C23", "C23", 
"-", "C19", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C10", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C04", "C13", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C13", "C10", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "C19", "C23", "-", "C13", "C23", "C19", 
"C23", "C04", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C13", "C23", 
"C10", "C04", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C04", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C04", "C10", "-", "C10", "C04", "C04", "C23", 
"-", "C23", "C10", "-", "C23", "C13", "C19", "C23", "C13", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C19", "-", "C04", "C23", "-", "C19", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C13", 
"C23", "C10", "C23", "C19", "C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "C19", 
"C19", "C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "-", "C23", "C23", "C13", "C23", 
"C23", "-", "C19", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "C13", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C10", "-", "C23", "C19", "C10", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C10", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C19", "C13", "C23", 
"C23", "-", "-", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "C23", 
"C23", "-", "C19", "C23", "C23", "C19", "-", "C19", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "C19", "C23", "C23", "C04", 
"C13", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C04", "C04", "C23", 
"C23", "C04", "C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C04", "C23", "-", "C23", 
"C23", "C13", "C19", "-", "C23", "C13", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C19", 
"C23", "C23", "-", "C10", "C19", "-", "-", "C13", "C19", "-", 
"C10", "C10", "C13", "-", "C10", "C23", "C10", "-", "C10", "C13", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "C10", "-", "C13", "C23", "-", 
"C23", "C13", "C23", "C23", "-", "C19", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C13", "C23", "C23", "C10", "C04", "C23", "-", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C10", "C23", "-", "C23", 
"-", "-", "C23", "C13", "-", "-", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "-", "C19", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C10", 
"C10", "-", "-", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C13", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"-", "C19", "C10", "-", "-", "C10", "-", "C13", "C10", "-", "C23", 
"C23", "C04", "C10", "C10", "-", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C23", 
"-", "C23", "C04", "C04", "C04", "C13", "C10", "C13", "C23", 
"C23", "-", "C13", "C19", "C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C13", "C23", "-", "-", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "-", "-", "C23", "-", "C10", "-", "C23", "-", "C04", 
"-", "-", "C10", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "C23", "C19", "C23", 
"C13", "-", "C13", "C23", "C19", "C23", "-", "C19", "C23", "-", 
"C19", "C19", "C10", "C23", "C10", "C23", "-", "C10", "C23", 
"C19", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C10", 
"C10", "C10", "C10", "C19", "C10", "C10", "C23", "-", "C19", 
"-", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C04", "C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "-", 
"C10", "C19", "-", "C23", "C10", "-", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C04", "C23", "C04", 
"C23", "C23", "-", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C19", "C10", "C10", 
"C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C04", "C19", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C04", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "C19", 
"C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "C19", "C19", "C19", "C19", "-", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C23", "-", "C10", "C19", "-", "C04", 
"C10", "C23", "C19", "C10", "-", "C10", "C10", "C13", "-", "C10", 
"C10", "C10", "-", "C10", "C10", "C10", "C10", "C19", "C10", 
"C10", "C23", "C04", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C19", "C19", "-", 
"C04", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "-", "C19", "-", "C19", 
"C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C10", "C19", "C23", 
"C19", "C23", "-", "C23", "C23", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C10", "C23", "C04", "C04", "-", "C10", "C23", "C04", "C23", 
"C10", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "C23", "-", "C19", 
"C10", "C23", "C19", "-", "C23", "-", "C04", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C19", "C10", "C10", "C10", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "C10", "C10", "C23", "C23", "C10", "C19", "C23", 
"C23", "-", "C23", "C04", "-", "C23", "-", "-", "C19", "C23", 
"C23", "C23", "-", "C19", "-", "C23", "C19", "-", "C23", "C19", 
"C23", "C10", "-", "C23", "C10", "C10", "-", "C10", "-", "-", 
"C10"), `Combi tag` = c("A15 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C04", 
"A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C10", "A09 + C10", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C13", 
"A23 + C21", "A23 + C10", "A15 + C13", "A09 + C23", "A15 + C13", 
"A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A15 + -", "A23 + C19", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A09 + C10", "A13 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A15 + C23", 
"A23 + C04", "A23 + C13", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A23 + -", "A13 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A13 + C13", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "- + -", "A23 + C10", 
"A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A15 + C19", "A15 + C23", "A09 + -", "A09 + C13", 
"A23 + C23", "A23 + C19", "A23 + C23", "A11 + C04", "A15 + C23", 
"A23 + C10", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A15 + C13", 
"A09 + C23", "A09 + C10", "A13 + C04", "A15 + C23", "A09 + -", 
"A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A11 + C23", "A11 + C04", "A15 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C04", "A09 + C10", "A15 + -", 
"A13 + C10", "A15 + C04", "A15 + C04", "A13 + C23", "A13 + -", 
"A23 + C23", "A23 + C10", "- + -", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C13", 
"A09 + C19", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C13", "A09 + C23", "A13 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A13 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A11 + C19", "A23 + -", 
"A09 + C04", "A15 + C23", "- + -", "- + C19", "A09 + C23", "A13 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C10", "A13 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C13", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C19", 
"A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A13 + -", "A23 + C19", 
"A09 + C19", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A13 + -", 
"A09 + -", "A13 + C23", "A13 + C23", "A15 + C13", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A15 + -", "A15 + C19", "A15 + C23", "A09 + -", 
"A13 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + -", "A09 + C23", "A13 + C13", 
"A15 + -", "A15 + -", "A13 + -", "A15 + -", "A15 + -", "A15 + -", 
"A15 + -", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C10", "A23 + -", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C19", "A23 + C10", 
"A23 + C23", "A11 + C10", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C10", "A23 + C23", 
"A20 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", 
"A13 + C19", "A23 + C13", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", "- + -", 
"A09 + -", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C10", "A13 + C23", "A23 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A13 + -", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A13 + -", 
"A15 + C19", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C19", "A23 + -", 
"A23 + C19", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", 
"A20 + C23", "A09 + C23", "- + -", "A09 + C19", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A23 + C04", "A09 + C13", "A13 + C23", "A15 + -", 
"A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C04", "A23 + C04", 
"A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C04", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", 
"- + -", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A13 + -", "A20 + C23", "A23 + C10", 
"A09 + C23", "A09 + C04", "A23 + C23", "A13 + -", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A11 + C13", "A15 + C19", "A23 + -", "A09 + C23", 
"A23 + C13", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A17 + C23", "A23 + C23", 
"A20 + C23", "A13 + -", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A13 + -", 
"A13 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C19", "A13 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A09 + -", "A09 + C10", "A23 + C19", "A13 + -", 
"- + -", "A09 + C13", "A09 + C19", "A09 + -", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C10", 
"A09 + C13", "A23 + -", "A09 + C10", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C10", 
"- + -", "A23 + C10", "A09 + C13", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A23 + -", "A09 + C23", "A11 + C10", "A23 + -", 
"A23 + C13", "A09 + C23", "A13 + -", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C13", 
"A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A09 + -", "A23 + C19", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + -", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C13", 
"A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C04", "A23 + C23", 
"A13 + -", "A23 + C23", "A11 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C10", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C10", "A09 + C23", "A09 + -", 
"A23 + C23", "A15 + -", "A13 + -", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C13", 
"A15 + -", "A23 + -", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A09 + -", 
"A09 + -", "A23 + C19", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A15 + C23", 
"A23 + C10", "A23 + C10", "A23 + -", "A13 + -", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C10", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C13", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A23 + -", "A23 + C19", "A09 + C10", "A23 + -", 
"A09 + -", "A15 + C10", "A23 + -", "A23 + C13", "A23 + C10", 
"A15 + -", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C04", "A23 + C10", 
"A23 + C10", "A23 + -", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A09 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A09 + -", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C04", "A09 + C04", 
"A09 + C04", "A23 + C13", "A23 + C10", "A13 + C13", "A23 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A09 + -", "A09 + C13", "A09 + C19", "A23 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "- + -", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", 
"A13 + C23", "A13 + C10", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", 
"A09 + C13", "A23 + C23", "A09 + -", "A23 + -", "A23 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A09 + -", "A23 + -", "A15 + C23", 
"A09 + -", "A23 + C10", "A23 + -", "A15 + C23", "A09 + -", "A23 + C04", 
"A23 + -", "A23 + -", "A23 + C10", "A09 + -", "A13 + -", "A09 + -", 
"A11 + -", "A13 + -", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C19", "A09 + C23", 
"A23 + C13", "- + -", "A09 + C13", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C19", 
"A09 + C23", "- + -", "A23 + C19", "A09 + C23", "A09 + -", "A15 + C19", 
"- + C19", "A09 + C10", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A09 + C23", 
"A15 + -", "A09 + C10", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C19", "A13 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A13 + C10", 
"A09 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C10", 
"A23 + C19", "A13 + C10", "A13 + C10", "A09 + C23", "A13 + -", 
"A15 + C19", "A15 + -", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C10", "A09 + C23", 
"A13 + C04", "A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A09 + -", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + -", "A13 + C10", "A09 + C19", "A15 + -", "A09 + C23", 
"A11 + C10", "A09 + -", "A13 + C23", "A23 + -", "A15 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C04", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C04", 
"A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + -", "A23 + C23", "A23 + -", 
"A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A13 + C19", "A23 + C10", "A13 + C10", 
"A11 + C23", "A09 + -", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C04", 
"A15 + C19", "A09 + C23", "A13 + -", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A13 + C04", "A15 + C23", "A11 + C10", "A23 + C23", 
"- + C23", "A11 + C23", "A15 + -", "A09 + C19", "A15 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", "- + -", "A23 + C19", "A23 + C19", 
"A13 + C19", "A09 + C19", "A15 + -", "- + C23", "A15 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", "- + -", 
"A23 + C10", "A23 + C19", "A15 + -", "A09 + C04", "A09 + C10", 
"A09 + C23", "A23 + C19", "A13 + C10", "A09 + -", "A09 + C10", 
"A09 + C10", "A11 + C13", "A23 + -", "A09 + C10", "A23 + C10", 
"A09 + C10", "A23 + -", "A09 + C10", "A09 + C10", "A09 + C10", 
"A23 + C10", "A22 + C19", "A09 + C10", "A09 + C10", "A13 + C23", 
"A23 + C04", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C19", 
"A23 + C19", "A15 + -", "A23 + C04", "A15 + C23", "A13 + C23", 
"A13 + C23", "- + C23", "A23 + -", "A09 + -", "A09 + C19", "A09 + -", 
"A09 + C19", "A23 + C23", "A09 + -", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", 
"A23 + C10", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A15 + C19", "A09 + C23", 
"A23 + C19", "A15 + C23", "- + -", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", 
"A09 + C10", "A13 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C10", 
"A15 + C23", "A23 + C04", "A23 + C04", "- + -", "A13 + C10", 
"A15 + C23", "A23 + C04", "A15 + C23", "A09 + C10", "A23 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C23", 
"A23 + -", "A09 + C19", "A23 + C10", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C19", 
"A15 + -", "A23 + C23", "A09 + -", "A23 + C04", "A15 + C23", 
"A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A15 + C23", "A13 + C19", "A23 + C10", 
"A23 + C10", "A13 + C10", "A09 + C10", "A09 + C23", "A09 + C23", 
"A09 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A09 + C10", 
"A23 + C23", "A23 + C23", "A23 + C10", "A23 + C19", "A09 + C23", 
"A23 + C23", "A09 + -", "A23 + C23", "A09 + C04", "A09 + -", 
"A15 + C23", "A13 + -", "A11 + -", "A23 + C19", "A15 + C23", 
"- + C23", "A23 + C23", "A09 + -", "A15 + C19", "A09 + -", "A09 + C23", 
"A15 + C19", "A15 + -", "A23 + C23", "A15 + C19", "A15 + C23", 
"A09 + C10", "A09 + -", "A09 + C23", "A15 + C10", "A15 + C10", 
"A09 + -", "A09 + C10", "- + -", "A09 + -", "A09 + C10")), row.names = c(NA, 
-671L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Resolved = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Tag1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Tag2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `Combi tag` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x000001f2b72f9050>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I use Tag1 and Tag2 as.factor for the facet top and right naming
The Resolved column are the months which go to the x-axis
In the graphs I want the percentage sum(unique combi tag, per month) / total tags(per month)

The ggplot2 code I have is

```
t <- ggplot(Code_csv_dummy_file, aes(x=Code_csv_dummy_file$Resolved, y=Code_csv_dummy_file$`Combi tag`)) + geom_point()
t + facet_grid(rows = vars(as.factor(Code_csv_dummy_file$Tag1)), cols = vars(as.factor(Code_csv_dummy_file$Tag2)))
```

I know it is the basic code, I seek help how to calculate the percentages to get them in the graphs

Thanks

Comment: Please include your sample data as a `dput()` output instead, i.e. result of `dput(Code_csv_dummy_file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also possible to aggregate over the same (or different) facet groups outside of ggplot, the exact percentage method might not exactly align with what was asked, but it should provide quite a straightforward example of how to handle such cases.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Code_csv_dummy_file %>% 
  add_count(Resolved, name = "total_per_month") %>% 
  add_count(Tag1, Tag2, Resolved, name = "combi_per_month") %>% 
  mutate(pct = combi_per_month / total_per_month) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(x = Resolved, y = pct)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(Tag1 ~ Tag2) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

[image]

Percentages on coloured bars and months in order:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Code_csv_dummy_file %>% 
  mutate(Resolved = lubridate::my(Resolved)) %>% 
  add_count(Resolved, name = "total_per_month") %>% 
  add_count(Tag1, Tag2, Resolved, name = "combi_per_month") %>% 
  mutate(pct = combi_per_month / total_per_month)  %>%
  distinct() %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Resolved, y = pct, fill = pct >= .10)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::label_percent(accuracy = .1)(pct)), nudge_y = .04, size = 3) +
  facet_grid(Tag1 ~ Tag2) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = scales::muted(c("green", "red"))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = .6), legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi your calculations on the percentages are the right ones, I cross checked with what I have now in excel.
Any suggestion how to turn this into bar with text label of the percentages on the bars? Like the other person has provided me?
Also I would like to get the months in order as they are in the file not mixed up. And each bar that is >= than 10% in red.
Any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: Sure. You are probably aware of all the duplicate values. Scatter plot kind of hides those by overplotting but they pop up when using `geom_col()`, hence the use of `distinct()`, and as you seem to agree with percentages, `distinct()` comes **after** calculations.

Comment: Thanks, looks great. I'm going to check the code of course to know how it works. Shouldn't be to hard but it has been like 6 years ago that I did my courses and now I have a chance to pick R up again, practically speaking. I checked only one percentage quickly but if the totals are nok I think I can manage further on my own. The duplicates in combi tag are on purpose, they represent tags on unique records and I want to plot in a clear way how many % of a combi came by over the total records in a month.

Comment: when I replicate with original data (which is same as dummy file but more columns) I get the behavior that it doesn't calculate the perc anymore correct and  that the perc label are flat on x-axis and the y-axis goes into the like 700% scale. I used the dummy file column headings but nok.
The only thing that R gives that is telling me something is nok is when I load in the data file.
"Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in assign(cacheKey, frame, .rs.CachedDataEnv) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name"

Comment: @PDG , that error seems seems to be reported issue - https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13188 . Is there a wide to long tranfarmetion somewhere in the workflow? If you say "more columns"  then  I'd suspect there to be Tag column for each value, though it would not explain empty Tags. I'm afraid there's not much we can do without having access to samples from dataset and/or having specific domain knowledge.

Comment: I installed previous version. Still doesn't work so I trouble shoot. It seems it only works when the CSV file only contains 3 columns (heading: Resolve, Tag1 and Tag2). If I have more columns, even tough the 3 columns with those headings are present, in the file the script does not work properly.
Can you explain why that is?

Comment: But anyway I know how to make it work now :) I just stick to the 3 columns and segregate by filename :). Thanks for the big help!